# HTTP ERROR when trying to upload an image in Nextgen gallery

Tags: .htaccess, internal-server-error, nextgen-gallery, php-ini, mod-fcgid

I am getting an error when trying to upload an image on NextGen gallery.
The error says:

> ERROR HTTP error.: HTTP Error.

When checking on developer tool it says:

> POST nextgen-gallery/admin/upload.php 500 (Internal Server Error)

I read on the internet that it may be the php.ini configuration (that limits the file size or process duration, but I couldn't solve it.
I also saw that it can be solved editing the HTACCESS file but it didn't lead me anywhere.

From what I saw it's related to the size of the image. Whenever the image is bigger than 100-150kb it's failing. But this is not for sure the problem. It can be the this is causing a large duration time to process and there is a limit of that which is creating eventually the error.

Do you have any advice?

Thanks.

---

UPDATE:

php configuration:

```
post_max_size 48M
upload_max_filesize 20M
```

Apache error.log:

```
mod_fcgid: HTTP request length 131768 (so far) exceeds MaxRequestLen (131072)
```

Comment: What do you see in apache error.log (on server)?

Answer (score 1):

There are two php.ini settings that limit upload file size:

1. [`post_max_size`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.post-max-size) - Sets max size of post data allowed. This setting also affects file upload. To upload large files, this value must be larger than `upload_max_filesize`
2. [`upload_max_filesize`](http://php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-max-filesize) - The maximum size of an uploaded file.

You can change these settings in php.ini (if they do not exist there yet, you can add).
OR, you can set them in .htaccess, like this:

```
php_value post_max_size 8M
php_value upload_max_filesize 1M
```

---

[mod_fcgid `FcgidMaxRequestLen` directive](https://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html#fcgidmaxrequestlen) can be configured only in **server config** or **virtual host config** (not in .htaccess)

Comment: These are my settings right now: post_max_size 48M 48M upload_max_filesize 20M 20M

Comment: Ok, then filesizes are probably not the problem. Do you have access to apache error.log ? See if there is anything being logged for the http 500 requests

Comment: mod_fcgid: HTTP request length 131768 (so far) exceeds MaxRequestLen (131072)

Comment: This means you need to look into `mod_fcgid` configuration, not php

Comment: That's what I am looking for. do you know the command line I need to use? (checking...)

Comment: Added information you discovered in comments and `mod-fcgid` tag to the question...

Comment: @tomastsc see update in the answer. you will need to configure it in httpd.conf or vhost (site configuration)

Answer (score 1):

As Poncha stated, none of the PHP directives being given as answers here have anything to do with the error that is in the Apache error log. To fix the 128k max upload size in the mod_fcid package on CentOS with Apache, type the following in your terminal window:

```
vim /etc/httpd/conf.d/fcgid.conf
```

Then add this to the end of the file:

```
# Set a larger size for uploads other than the default 128k
MaxRequestLen 1073741824
```

Then restart Apache with this:

```
/etc/init.d/httpd restart
```

All done!